# How do you get a closed vessel to >90,000 psi internal pressure

Tags: pressure, hydraulics, process-engineering, pressure-vessel

Im trying to build a cold isostatic press with a internal vessel area of 300mm3.
A cold isostatic press forms green metal components using pressures greater than 90,000 psi.
Using an oil or water/emulsified oil solution do they use a high pressure pump and connect it to a hydraulic intensifier?
Any direction is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about the force on the green metal in a die or pressure in a vessel ?

Answer (score 3):

Contact an engineering firm with experience designing and building such systems and vessels to code. Otherwise, you're just building a bomb.

Comment: There's really nothing else that can be done here.  That's an extremely high pressure vessel and is likely governed by specific codes in your area (and for good reason).  You do not want one of those blowing up.  I'm also a bit confused, as this seems to be a very small vessel ($300 m^3$ is less than $7 mm \times 7 mm \times 7 mm$.

Comment: The safety aspects make me shudder if it goes wrong...

Comment: 90000 psi? steels usually have UTS at 70ksi.

Comment: There are super alloys available that have yield above 200 ksi. Used in aerospace frequently. Very expensive though.